# When the form throws validation messages to the user, the drop-down nav breaks on the site

Tags: forms, codeigniter, drop-down-menu, controller, responsive-design

RESOLVED: In the contact controller i had `function index` with the page location then a separate one called `function send_mail`. I removed the send_mail function and moved the code up to the index function which when the email was sent or error messages thrown back it kept the url as /contact not /contact/send_mail and now the drop-down menu now works! Of course on my contact view i changed  `echo form_open('contact/send_email');` to  echo `form_open('contact');`

---

I have built a responsive website using the Codeigniter Framework.

When the screen size shrinks to a mobile/tablet width, the navigation changes from buttons to a drop-down select menu.

I have a function in my controller called send_mail and when the user clicks the form they will receive either an error message if they filled in the form incorrect or a success message and in the url when this button is clicked the send_mail is added on the end of it.

The form does submit and all works but when testing; only when the responsive site changes to the drop-down select menu and the send_mail is added to the end of the url, you can not navigate to another page - it just stays on the same page.

At the moment i am testing and i have built the site on a localhost so unsure if it is just this or a possible solution to this?

In this post i havent added any code in (but can if it helps) as i was asking as a guidance or a suggestion why this doesn't work? Is this something to do with my media queries or drop-down as even though the send_mail is on the end it still works when it is the other widths as buttons??

CODE is below:

Is there a possible way of hiding the send_email function in the url in the routes folder when the form is submitted so it just shows `http:///www.websitename/contact` instead of `http:///www.websitename/contact/email_send` or is this something to do with the "if statement" when the user is sent back to the form?

Again everything works perfectly when the site is resized using the standard nav ul styling at other widths, just the dropdown which is hidden until it is displayed in the media query.

HTML for Select Menu (This is hidden unless mobile version)

```
        <option value="" selected="selected">MENU</option>  

                <option value="Home">Home</option> 
                <option value="about">About</option> 
                <option value="testimonials">Testimonials</option> 
                <option value="blog">Blog</option> 
                <option value="contact">Contact</option> 
            </select>
```

CSS media query(MOBILE)

```
nav ul     { display: none; }
nav select { display: inline-block; }
```

Jquery for Responsive Nav

send_email function in Contact Controller

```
public function send_email (){

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Name','trim|required|htmlspecialchars|max_length[30]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email Address','trim|valid_email|required|htmlspecialchars|max_length[100]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('message','Message','trim|required|htmlspecialchars|xss_clean');

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div id="errors">&bull;&nbsp;','</div>');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $data['success'] = '';
            $data['page_title'] = 'Contact';
            $data['content'] = 'contact';
            $this->load->view('template', $data);

        }else{

            $data['success'] = 'The email has successfully been sent';
            $data['name'] = $this->input->post('name');
            $data['email'] = $this->input->post('email');
            $data['message'] = $this->input->post('message');

            $html_email = $this->load->view('html_email', $data, true);

            //load the email class
            $this->load->library('email');

            $this->email->from(set_value('email'), set_value('name'));
            $this->email->to('emailaddressusuallyhere');
            $this->email->subject('Message from Website');
            $this->email->message($html_email);

            $this->email->send();

            $data['success'] = 'The email has successfully been sent';
            $data['page_title'] = 'Contact';
            $data['content'] = 'contact';   
            $this->load->view('template', $data);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED: In the contact controller i had function index with the page location then a separate one called function send_mail. I removed the send_mail function and moved the code up to the index function which when the email was sent or error messages thrown back it kept the url as /contact not /contact/send_mail and now the drop-down menu now works! Of course on my contact view i changed echo form_open('contact/send_email'); to echo form_open('contact');